# I'm trying to set JTextField under JLabel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, jtextfield

I'm trying to put the text field under the `JLabel`. Currently, the text field is displayed on the same line. It should be below and centered. I need assistance.

```
package Gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class ShowGridLayout extends JFrame {

    public ShowGridLayout() {
        // Set GridLayout, 3 rows, 2 columns, and gaps 5 between
        // components horizontally and vertically
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 5, 5));

        // Add labels and text fields to the frame

        JLabel firstname = new JLabel("First Name");
        add(firstname);

        JTextField fistnametextField = new JTextField(8);
        add(fistnametextField);

        JLabel mi = new JLabel("Mi");
        add(mi);

        JTextField miTextField = new JTextField(1);
        add(miTextField);

        JLabel lastname = new JLabel("Last Name");
        add(lastname);

        JTextField lastnameTextField = new JTextField(8);
        add(lastnameTextField);
    }

    /**
    * Main method
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShowGridLayout frame = new ShowGridLayout();
        frame.setTitle("ShowGridLayout");
        frame.setSize(200, 125);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I need assistance"*  You need a question.  Do you have a question?  (A help-desk provides assistance - *this* OTOH is a Q&A site.)

Comment: Sorry dear, i'm french speaking. I'll follow your advice the next time ask a question. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use a `GridLayout` with a single column:

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
```

Note that `GridLayout` will ignore the preferred sizes of the `JTextFields` so using the constructor `JTextField(int columnSize)` will have no effect so the default constructor will do.

Also I would remove the internal spacing here and add a border to the `JFrame`:

```
(JComponent)getContentPane()).setBorder(   
      BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10) );
```

This would produce a frame that looks like

[image: Centered JTextFields]

Comment: Thank you dear. It was so easy. I'm so tired i cant think anymore. Cheers

Comment: Also consider `GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5))`.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a 3x2 grid. That is, 3 rows of 2 columns each. the first call to add() will put the component in row 1, col 1 and the second call will put the component in row 1 col 2. So they are next to each other. With GridLayout you do not have much control over this. If you want items to be one over the next you can try a 3x1 grid. Or you can try adding components in a different order. Or you can try a different layout manager such as GridBagLayout where you have more control.